# CSS - Photo Library

Tags: css, class, html, background-image

I'm working on a simple photo gallery/library. So far, I'm only up to the CSS. I have a 2 by 3 grid of divs (soon to be the photo icons).

What I'm trying to do is give each div icon a unique background image. Now how would I do that as each icon div use the same class 'photo_holder'?

If I change the background for that class... it changes all the images. What I don't want is to have 'photo_holder_1' and 'photo_holder_2', and so on.

The photo_holder holds a quite a lot of elements (main reason why I don't want to have duplicates).

Is there away to give my divs each a unique ID, so I can have CSS to replace the background image?

Thanks

Comment: What's the actual behaviour that you want? Do you want to alternate images, or randomly choose them, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each can have unique id and multiple classes.

```
<div id="hld_1" class="holder frame size etc"> .. </div>
```

then in css

effect for right one element:

```
#hld_1 { background ... }
```

all elements having

```
.holder { ... }
```

Comment: Ah, perfect! I have no idea you could have class and ids in one div :)